# Android Studio error "this document contains very long lines. soft wraps were forcibly enabled to improve editor performance."

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

[image]**Everything was working properly but suddenly i am getting every java file in wired format with above error.**

Comment: What is the question? Android Studio clearly does not like you code style

Comment: Everything was working properly but suddenly i am getting every java file in wired format with above error.

Comment: Hi I don't know what happens but re importing project worked for me!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are pasting xml content into java file - Android Studio parser does not know what to do. Create proper .xml file for that content

Comment: Thanks for comment, But i have not added anything in java file it was a working code and it automatically happens with all my java files become like a xml.

Comment: @SagarSah you are the only one who knows why you have xml code in java file, this is wrong and must be fixed.

Comment: Yes, and you really need to improve the question with more details to get any good answers